# saving figure to eps format without using imshow

Tags: matlab, save, eps

There have been some posts here regarding image processing but I don't think that this question has been asked here. I have Matlab but not the image processing toolbox. I've tried to compress a figure and I want to save the result in the eps format. I have looked at imwrite but it doesn't have the eps format. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: This post is also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478633/matlab-write-image-into-eps-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for b&w eps

```
 saveas(fig, 'myfile.eps', 'eps')
```

for color

```
saveas(fig, 'myfile.eps', 'eps2c')
```

documentation:

> SAVEAS(H,'FILENAME','FORMAT')
>       Will save the Figure or Simulink block diagram  with handle H to file 
>       called FILENAME in the format specified by FORMAT. FORMAT can be the 
>       same values as extensions of FILENAME.
>
> Additional FORMAT options include devices allowed by PRINT.

type help print for a list of drivers.  You don't need the '-d' part when calling saveas.

if your question is how to display an image in the figure window without using imshow, either image or imagesc will work (if imagesc, convert to a double first)

```
imagesc(double(im)); colormap gray; axis equal
saveas(gcf, 'myimage.eps', 'eps')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I needed your "second" answer and I added  axis off; axis image to get the image only. Some good information also here: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/image.html